# Elementary Functions, Differentiation, Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, elementary-functions

Why is it that differentiation of a function that is a composition of elementary functions (such as $\sin \:2^x$ or $\ln(\mathrm{arcsec}\: x^3)$ or $x^{1/x}$) always produces a composition of elementary functions, while integration sometimes does not? For example, the derivative of $\sin \:x^2$ is $2x\cos \:x^2$, but the integral of $\sin \:x^2$ produces the Fresnel sine function, the definition of which is simply the integral? To put it loosely, why does differentiation make functions simpler and integration make functions more complex? I guess what I'm trying to get at is **what fundamental aspect of integration sometimes produces a non-elementary function from an elementary function?**

Comment: The derivative of $\sin x^2$ is $2x\cos x^2$.

Comment: Oops, I've corrected it.

Comment: But there also some functions that differentiating them is harder than integrating. For example $2x\cos x^2$, its anti-derivative is $\sin x^2$ and its derivative is $2\cos x^2-4x^2 \sin x^2 $

Comment: One actually does not need to go further than the natural logarithm. Who'd expect that $\int \frac1{u}\mathrm du$ results in a *transcendental* function?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you are looking for is
"integration in finite terms".

Here is one of
the key papers in the field:

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-139-00/S0002-9947-1969-0237477-8/S0002-9947-1969-0237477-8.pdf

A useful book
which I read many years ago is
 J. F. Ritt, Integration in finite terms, Liouville's theory of elementary methods, Columbia
Univ. Press, New York, 1948.